# bind9 resolves all queries to one address - a compromised server?

Tags: dns, dns-spoofing

Since this morning we tried to open some SSL sites and were greeted by browser warnings, that certificate is not for this site. Upon checking the certificate, we determined that it is issued to *.hostgator.com. Since it happened to every site we normally visit, I immediately tried pinging some of them and all queries returned response of:

`64 bytes from gator4226.hostgator.com (108.167.189.52): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=141 ms`

We have two on-site DNS servers, one is bind9 on ubuntu (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.) I stopped the service, then an old win2k3 took over, and ping responses returned to being proper again. I guess our bind9 was successfully attacked, so that even if it restarts, it immediately returns wrong IPs for all queries. Since I don't allow external requests (from the Internet), I guess one of our own users must have done something. Maybe they were pissed off because we block facebook, I don't know.

**My questions are:**

- Is it possible to determine how this happened?
- Could it be an attack from Internet after all?

**Some more info on our bind9 config**

It is actually a master to our own domain. We have some services on-site, including web and mail. We have normal, commercially issued SSL certificates. Our DNS makes our domain resolve to local IP, instead of public (and we can browse for, e.g. mail.mycompany.com, and our web browsers don't complain about certs). Besides that functionality, it's just a forwarder. Also we made some unwanted sites resolve to 127.0.0.1 and disallowed any traffic on port 59 for other hosts on our network, besides these two DNS servers.

`named.conf` includes just three files: `named.conf.options`, `named.conf.local` and `named.conf.default-zones`. Below are relevant files. I hid my actual domain name by replacing it with *mydomain.com*.

**named.conf.options**

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    forwarders {
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
            213.172.186.4;
            216.172.186.5;
            #194.105.133.2;
            #194.105.133.1;
    };
    allow-query {
            192.168.0/24;
            127.0.0.1;
    };

    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { none; };
};
```

**named.conf.local**

```
zone "mydomain.com" { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.mydomain.com"; };
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.192.168.0"; };

zone "facebook.com" { type master; file "/etc/bind/blockedsites"; };
zone "facebook.pl" { type master; file "/etc/bind/blockedsites"; };
zone "hide.me" { type master; file "/etc/bind/blockedsites"; };
zone "hidemyass.com" { type master; file "/etc/bind/blockedsites"; };
zone "best-proxy.pl" { type master; file "/etc/bind/blockedsites"; };
```

**finally, file used to respond to any blocked (sort of) sites - blockedsites**

```
;
; BIND data file for local net
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     mysite.local.   hostmaster.mysite.local. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns0.mysite.local.
@       IN      A       127.0.0.1
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
*       IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

So, I'm completely at a loss as to where should I look for potential causes for this problem. If anyone would be kind enough to explain what could have happened, or redirect me to similar incidents with resolutions, I'd be most grateful.

**EDIT**

**This machine is NOT a router, it provides DNS, DHCP and TFTP**. Output of neststat -nr is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt     Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Obviously, output of `iptables -t nat -L` is empty, because this machine doesn't do NAT. That's the router's job, which is at above seen 192.168.0.1.

ps -uax output is:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.2  0.1  33508  4072 ?        Ss   09:27   0:01 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [kworker/u128:0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/0]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/1]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/2]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/3]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/4]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/5]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/6]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/7]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/8]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/9]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/10]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/11]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/12]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/13]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/14]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/15]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/16]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/17]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/18]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/19]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/20]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/21]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/22]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/23]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/24]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/25]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/26]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/27]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/28]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/29]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/30]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/31]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/32]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/33]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/34]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/35]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/36]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/37]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/38]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/39]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/40]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/41]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/42]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/43]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/44]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/45]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/46]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/47]
root        56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/48]
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/49]
root        58  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/50]
root        59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/51]
root        60  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/52]
root        61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/53]
root        62  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/54]
root        63  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/55]
root        64  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/56]
root        65  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/57]
root        66  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/58]
root        67  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/59]
root        68  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/60]
root        69  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/61]
root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/62]
root        71  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuos/63]
root        72  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root        73  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/0]
root        74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/1]
root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/2]
root        76  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/3]
root        77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/4]
root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/5]
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/6]
root        80  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/7]
root        81  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/8]
root        82  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/9]
root        83  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/10]
root        84  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/11]
root        85  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/12]
root        86  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/13]
root        87  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/14]
root        88  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/15]
root        89  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/16]
root        90  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/17]
root        91  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/18]
root        92  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/19]
root        93  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/20]
root        94  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/21]
root        95  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/22]
root        96  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/23]
root        97  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/24]
root        98  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/25]
root        99  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/26]
root       100  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/27]
root       101  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/28]
root       102  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/29]
root       103  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/30]
root       104  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/31]
root       105  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/32]
root       106  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/33]
root       107  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/34]
root       108  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/35]
root       109  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/36]
root       110  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/37]
root       111  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/38]
root       112  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/39]
root       113  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/40]
root       114  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/41]
root       115  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/42]
root       116  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/43]
root       117  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/44]
root       118  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/45]
root       119  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/46]
root       120  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/47]
root       121  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/48]
root       122  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/49]
root       123  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/50]
root       124  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/51]
root       125  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/52]
root       126  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/53]
root       127  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/54]
root       128  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/55]
root       129  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/56]
root       130  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/57]
root       131  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/58]
root       132  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/59]
root       133  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/60]
root       134  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/61]
root       135  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/62]
root       136  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [rcuob/63]
root       137  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [migration/0]
root       138  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root       139  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root       140  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [migration/1]
root       141  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root       143  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root       144  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [khelper]
root       145  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root       146  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [netns]
root       147  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root       148  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [writeback]
root       149  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   09:27   0:00 [ksmd]
root       150  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   09:27   0:00 [khugepaged]
root       151  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [crypto]
root       152  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root       153  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [bioset]
root       154  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [kblockd]
root       155  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [ata_sff]
root       156  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [khubd]
root       157  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [md]
root       158  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root       159  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [kworker/u128:1]
root       160  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [kworker/0:1]
root       161  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [kworker/1:1]
root       163  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [kswapd0]
root       164  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root       165  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root       177  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [kthrotld]
root       178  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
root       179  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       180  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root       181  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       182  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root       184  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root       185  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [kworker/0:2]
root       186  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [kworker/u128:3]
root       205  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [deferwq]
root       206  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [charger_manager]
root       250  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       251  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_con]
root       253  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       256  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       258  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       259  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       260  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       261  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       262  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       263  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       264  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       265  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       266  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       267  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       268  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root       269  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       270  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
root       280  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
root       281  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       287  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [hv_vmbus_ctl]
root       288  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:27   0:00 [kworker/1:2]
root       414  0.0  0.0  19612  2000 ?        S    09:27   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       419  0.0  0.1  51648  3752 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
message+   511  0.0  0.1  39232  2496 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
syslog     563  0.0  0.1 255848  2952 ?        Ssl  09:27   0:00 rsyslogd
root       581  0.0  0.1  43456  3244 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root       888  0.0  0.1  15936  2444 ?        S    09:27   0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
root       891  0.0  0.0  15660  2012 ?        S    09:27   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root       927  0.0  0.1  15824  2064 tty4     Ss+  09:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       930  0.0  0.0  15824  2016 tty5     Ss+  09:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       938  0.0  0.1  15824  2072 tty2     Ss+  09:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       940  0.0  0.1  15824  2064 tty3     Ss+  09:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       948  0.0  0.0  15824  2024 tty6     Ss+  09:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root       987  0.0  0.2  61376  5356 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
dhcpd      988  0.0  0.3  17644  6248 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 dhcpd -user dhcpd -group dhcpd -f -q -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
root      1000  0.0  0.0   4372  1560 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
daemon    1010  0.0  0.0  19144   164 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 atd
root      1011  0.0  0.1  23660  2252 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 cron
root      1017  0.0  0.0  15132   168 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/in.tftpd --listen --user tftp --address 0.0.0.0:69 --secure -m /etc/tftpd.map /var/li
root      1044  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:27   0:00 [kworker/1:1H]
root      1053  0.0  0.1  19196  2196 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
root      1076  0.0  0.0  15824  2024 tty1     Ss+  09:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root      1137  0.0  0.3 105644  6480 ?        Ss   09:30   0:00 sshd: kitet [priv]
root      1139  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:30   0:00 [kauditd]
kitet     1186  0.0  0.1 105644  3504 ?        R    09:30   0:00 sshd: kitet@pts/0
kitet     1187  0.0  0.2  22592  5388 pts/0    Ss   09:30   0:00 -bash
bind      1221  0.0  1.1 245200 23888 ?        Ssl  09:31   0:00 /usr/sbin/named -4 -u bind
root      1240  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:32   0:00 [kworker/u128:2]
kitet     1249  0.0  0.1  18452  2628 pts/0    R+   09:35   0:00 ps -uax
```

**EDIT2: ifconfig -a**

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:00:e6:02
      inet addr:192.168.0.233  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:22006 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6771 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:2076222 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:719723 (719.7 KB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:7003 (7.0 KB)  TX bytes:7003 (7.0 KB)
```

Comment: If they have attacked your servers. Someone is probably playing games with your inexperience, and taking revenge on you. Maybe ARP poisoning inside your network. Hint: if I am not wrong, they may do it again. Enlist the help [Hire] of an external systems and security consultant ASAP. Connect the server to a crossed-over cable, and test it to make sure wether it was changed.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want me to chceck for changes using that crossover cable. I am logged via ssh to that dns, so if something else would be on that IP/MAC i would not connect, right? Or what else could have changed? By the way "they" not only MAY do it again, it's happening when I turn on bind9 service. Not immediately (in the morning it WAS immediately), but eventually DNS starts sending these bogus responses.

Comment: You could test for DNS requests with the crossover. The DNS conf seems ok, how about the routes? `netstat -nr`? what out for nat, `sudo iptables -t nat -L`

Comment: router seems ok. how the iptables command and `ps uax`
 please

Comment: I added requested info in edit. I'm currently looking into detecting arp spoofs.

Comment: so far all seems ok. `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: Also seems normal, at least not different from other linux boxes we have.

Comment: Are the DNS servers given by the DHCP server still the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34702/discussion-between-kitet-and-rui-f-ribeiro).